# Can't run 'ng' from VSTS agent

Tags: build, azure-devops, angular-cli

I'm trying to run unit tests against our AngularCLI project using our hosted VSTS build agents however it keeps running into trouble when it tries to run 'ng test'.

To resolve this I have tried to make the agent use the ng tool directly by providing the path to the tool. This hasn't worked as it looks like it's trying to run 'ng test' where the tool is rather than in the specified current working directory:

[image]

[image]

I've also tried to add it as an environment variable in Windows (we're using Windows Server 2012 to host the VSTS agent) and setting the tool in the VSTS agent as just `ng` however it doesn't appear to be finding the ng tool:

[image]
[image]

How can I get the VSTS agent to make use of the `ng` tool to run tests? We have got @angular/cli installed on the server hosting the agent.

Comment: What's the result if you run the `ng test` command in the agent machine directly?

Comment: It works fine if we run it locally, however we're running it from our own user accounts on the machine rather than the NetworkService account which the VSTS agent runs from

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The thing is that you won't get angular cli installed on VSTS globally as its build server is not supporting that. But the good thing you not even need cli globally installed on your agent.

All you need is `npm run ng build -- prod` - this way it will always run the local version. Also this way you won't need to take care of updating your global package at all.

Use `npm run ng test` to run tests, `npm run ng e2e` to run protractor. If you need to pass any more params to any of these just use `--`

Comment: Thanks Kuncevic, running ng test using npm rather than a cmd got it working :)

Comment: The extra "--" to pass args to ng was the missing bit that I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @Kuncevic, to use the Angular CLI without installing it globally, you will need to use the `npm run` command.

To run an Angular build using Azure Devops:

1. Add an `npm` task to install dependencies (choose `install` for the command)
2. Add another `npm` task, but choose `custom` for the command. Then add your `command and arguments`:

`run ng -- build --output-path=dist --configuration=prod`

Note how `npm` is not a part of the `command and arguments` since this will be provided by the task. Also note how `--` separates the command to be run and the arguments to be passed to the command.